# How to get more than 10 results from the OMDb API?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

I'm trying to output more than 10 results using this movie API https://www.omdbapi.com/. The documentation doesn't provide any parameters for this purpose. I've tried combining pages but it doesn't work or maybe I'm just not doing it the right way. Any ideas?

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
  const getFilm = () => {
    let pages = 5
    fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=36e8742&s=${film}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => pages = data.totalResults / 10)
    if (film.length) {
      for(let i = 0; i <= pages ;i++){
        fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=36e8742&s=${film}&page=${i}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setMovies(...movies,data.Search))
      }
      console.log(movies)

      setFilm('')
      Keyboard.dismiss()
    } else Keyboard.dismiss()
  }
```

Comment: I'm guessing the api spits out a fixed amount of items per page since it **only** has `page` api parameter. You will need to combine pages to increase the items to 20, 30 and so on

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to [TMDb API](https://www.themoviedb.org/) instead. It provides a lot more than 10 results for a search.